# I can't see the "Modify" option on the Stored Proedures, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: management-studio-express

Since I updated my Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio last week I can't see the option "Modify" my Stored Proecedures. When I click the right mouse key on the stored procedure I just can see:

- Stored Procedure...
- Script Stored Procedure as...
- Policies
- Facets
- Start Powershell
- Reports
- Rename
- Delete
- Refresh

Any idea how to modify the stored procedures?

My Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version is: 13.0.15500.91

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

This happend, because the SQL Server version where I was connected, was different, so then I couldn't use the "Modify" and "Edit 200 rows" options.